# Rails responds with status code 406

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, http-status-code-406, actiondispatch

I have been working on a test for my function inside Ruby on Rails. However, the test (which expects a status code of `:success`) fails after receiving a status code `406`. Here's the exact failure log:

```
Failure: Expected response to be a <:success>, but was <406>.
test_should_post_comment_through_token_successfully(CommentControllerTest)
test/functional/comment_controller_test.rb:271:in `block in <class:CommentControllerTest>'
```

I read a little about the `406` response, and found out that it stands of "Not Acceptable". so I tried setting the `Accept`, `Content-Type`, `Accept-Language` and `Accept-Charset` headers but I have had no luck.

Here's the code for my test:

```
test 'should post comment through token successfully' do
  @params = {
    id: 1,
    body: "Test Comment",
    username: "Bob"
  }

  @headers = {
    "Accept" => "application/json",
    "Accept-Language" => "en-US",
    "Accept-Charset" => "utf-8",
    "Content-Type" => "application/json",
    "Token" => "abcdefg12345"
  }

  get :create_by_token, @params, @headers
  assert_response :success
end
```

The `create_by_token` function inside the controller:

```
def create_by_token
  @node = Node.find params[:id]
  @user = User.find_by_username params[:username]
  @body = params[:body]
  @token = request.headers['Token']
  p request.headers["Accept"]
  p request.headers["Content-Type"]
  p request.headers["Token"]

  if @user && @user.token == @token
    begin
      @comment = create_comment(@node, @user, @body)
      msg = {
        status: :created,
        message: "Created"
      }
      respond_to do |format|
        format.xml { render xml: msg.to_xml }
        format.json { render json: msg.to_json }
      end
    rescue CommentError
      msg = {
        status: :bad_request,
        message: "Bad Request"
      }
      respond_to do |format|
        format.xml { render xml: msg.to_xml }
        format.json { render json: msg.to_json }
      end
    end
  else
    msg = {
      status: :unauthorized,
      message: "Unauthorized"
    }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { render xml: msg.to_xml }
      format.json { render json: msg.to_json }
    end
  end
end
```

My route:

```
post '/bot/comment.:format', to: 'comment#create_by_token'
```

Am I missing something crucial? How do I go about solving this issue?

I would be happy to provide any other information you would need.

Comment: Without seeing the actual controller code we unlikely could help.

Comment: @mudasobwa I will add the concerned function too.

Comment: @mudasobwa done.

Comment: I don't know about your particular problem but I'd advise you to start digging for the root of the problem yourself by debugging. Install `pry-byebug` (which is the debugger I use for rails apps, there are other solutions) and set [debug] breakpoints using `binding.pry`. Start setting breakpoints in a top-down manner, if you can't isolate the problematic parts on first glance (-> if-clause) thus incrementally analysing the flow through the [controller] code. Most times this is way faster than posting on SO and waiting for a response. Hope that helps, good luck

Comment: Thanks, @A.Neumann. I will definitely try that.

Comment: If you experience any problems during debugging don't hesitate to ask for further help by starting a chat!

Comment: @A.Neumann need atleast 20 reputation to do that :/
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why do you test creation with **`GET`** request: `get :create_by_token, @params, @headers`? It should be **`POST`**, shouldn’t it?

Comment: @Ryzokuken in this particular case the debugger is of very little help, unless you are to put a breakpoint deeply inside Rails middleware.

Comment: @mudasobwa I will try using POST instead, thanks. Although, I doubt that's the issue because in that case, it would have thrown a 405 "Method Not Allowed" status.

Comment: @mudasobwa yep, no luck.

Comment: @mudasobwa: You surely do not need to digg into the middleware to test basic HTTP request handling by the controller... simply put breakpoints into the relevant parts of the controller and see what's happening in the context of your test/spec.

Comment: Show your `routes.rb`.

Comment: @A.Neumann this request is evidently **not handled by a controller**, Rails returns a response without even getting into a controller. I believe you’d better learn a bit of Rails before using words like “surely.”

Comment: @mudasobwa would I need to add a route for this for this purpose? I did not add one yet, I think.

Comment: If you expect the request to be routed, then yes, you need to add a route. Rails does a lot of magic, but it does not code for you :)

Comment: @mudasobwa I knew I would need a route later when I wanted to use it, but not if I wanted to test it. Adding a route. Do I need to add all params in the route URL, or will `/api/comment.:format` work?

Comment: It heavily depends on your intent. For `POST` with a body as above, `/api/comment.:format` would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, stupid me. I realized that among all the params I was passing, the format was also being passed inside the URL. However, as in the test I was not mentioning a URL which I could pass in the format as the suffix (`.xml` or `.json`), I would have to mention the `format` inside the params explicitly. Here's the updated test code:

```
test 'should post comment through token successfully' do
  @params = {
    id: 1,
    body: "Test Comment",
    username: "Bob",
    format: 'json'
  }

  @headers = {
    "token" => "abcdefg12345"
  }

  post :create_by_token, @params, @headers
  assert_response :success
end
```

Kudos @Sowmiya for leading me to this conclusion. Your answer was not exactly the solution I needed, but it provoked me to think.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this might be an error with respond_to do block. Kindly check with the routes whether you have configured as resources or resource.

Do update to resources than singular which will help with respond_to do block.

You can also try update your routes as/;

```
resources :samples, defaults: {format: :json}
```

Comment: I added my route up above. Please check if there's a problem with it.